# Angular material 2 - How to keep mat-option selected when switching routes?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I tried to use `ngOnChanges` to keep the option selected previously when I switch away after selecting a value, then I come back the previous route, but the selected option returns to None as default. How can I keep track of the most recent selected option between switching routes?.

Here is my code:

Select view:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Choose a pair" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" 
  (ngModelChange)="emit($event)">
  <mat-option>--None--</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let token of tokens" [value]="token.id">
    {{token.name}}
  </mat-option>        
</mat-select>

<a *ngFor="let token of tokens" [routerLink]="['/tokens/', token.id]">
  <span *ngIf="selectedValue===token.id">
    More about {{token.name}}
  </span>          
</a>
```

Select component:

```
selectedValue: any;
tokens: any;

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTokens();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.selectedValue) {
      this.selectedValue = this.tokens.find(i => i.id === this.selectedValue.id
        && i.name === this.selectedValue.name);
    }
  }

  emit(selectedValue) {
    this.sharedService.pair.next(selectedValue);
  }

  loadTokens() {
    this.apiService.getTokens()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.tokens = data;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you route away, your component is destroyed. This means that any variable you had in it is destroyed with it.

To keep a value, you can either use a service, or the local/session storage.

(I would recommend using a service, but that's my personal opinion).

By the way, `ngOnChanges` works only with Inputs (`@Input`), and I highly doubt that you will have inputs in a routed component.

Comment: Right, I can try a service